# Prematurely resetting the stack pointer? Confusing assembly code

Tags: assembly, x86, reverse-engineering, stack-frame

Im trying to make sense of a small bit of assembly.

```
pushl %ebp
movl %esp,%ebp
movl 8(%ebp),%edx
movl 12(%ebp),%eax
movl %ebp,%esp
movl (%edx),%edx
addl %edx,(%eax)
movl %edx,%eax
popl %ebp
ret
```

Why is the sp being reset to the base pointer before the rest of the function? Why is the value in %edx being moved back into itself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A shorter version of this would be:

```
mov 4(%esp), %eax
mov 8(%esp), %edx
mov (%edx), %edx
add  %edx, (%eax)
ret
```

or, a rough C equiv:

```
void add(int *from, int *to) {
  *to += *from;
}
```

The compiler likely plays with %ebp go ensure debug-able stack frames; and restoring %esp from %ebp does nothing -- they are the same value.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply, yeah the intended function is supposed to be basically that. I still don't really understand what this is doing: ```movl (%edx), %edx```

Comment: *%edx* contains a pointer (*from*), so that de-references the pointer to get the value at its location.   compile the "C" version with -S to see what your compiler generates; then play with options like -O4 and see what it can reduce it to.

Answer (score 1):

> Why is the sp being reset to the base pointer before the rest of the function?

In GNU Assembler syntax, `movl %esp,%ebp` means that `esp` is moved to `ebp`.
(GNU asm syntax has always the opposite order of two and more args from Intel asm syntax).

This creates stack frame: local variables and parameters can be referenced relative to `%ebp`, as in `movl 8(%ebp),%edx`.

`popl %ebp` restores the original `%ebp`, saved by `pushl %ebp`.

---

> Why is the value in %edx being moved back into itself?

In GNU Assembler syntax, `(%edx)` is an indirection of the pointer in `%edx`; note that it is again the source operand.

Comment: VLAs were new in C99.  C11 still has them, of course, but we normally say C99 VLAs.

Comment: @PeterCordes, actually removed that partl. `%esp` in this function does not change at all.

Comment: Right, other than via push/pop of course, so the `movl %ebp,%esp` is just a missed optimization (because optimization was presumably not enabled), not necessary for `-fno-omit-frame-pointer`.